# How to multiply the font size in html? ActionScript 3 implemention

Tags: html, actionscript-3, input, output, font-size

Please read the examples compare input and output. Defrent is in size=[Values]. How to replace it?

```
input:
"<font size='30'> Head </font><br></br> <font color='#b5fe01' size='50'>Progress:</font>"
```

and I want multiply all font sizes by 2 and replace it in original input.

```
output:
"<font size='60'> Head </font><br></br> <font color='#b5fe01' size='100'>Progress:</font>"
```

Thanks

Comment: Be more specific on what you want... This is really unclear

Comment: Please read the examples and compare input, output. Defrent is in Values

Comment: @Michal Gabriel Do you want to modify your fonts size in a swf (embedded using SWFObject)?

Comment: @helloflash No I have this Html String and I can parse it and replace (devided, multiply) size values

Comment: @Deer-Outdoor.nl I edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS3 regexp as requested:

```
var multiply:Function = function(matched:String, start:String, size:String, index:int, str:String):String
{
    return start + (2 * int(size)).toString() + "'";
}

var match:RegExp = /(<font[^>]*size=')(\d+)'/gi;
var src:String = "<font size='30'> Head </font><br/> <font color='#b5fe01' size='50'>Progress:</font>";

var replaced:String = src.replace(match, multiply);
```

Explanation:

1. multiply - Takes "start" and "size" params. "start" is the previously matched part of font tag. This is required as we need to know we are in font tag, yet we only want to replace the size value. "size" is the actual size value.
2. RegExp - Captures as first group "<font" followed by any number of non-'>' characters, followed by "size='". Second group is the value of size. match is finished with "'" after size value, which is not captured. g stands for "global" and makes multiple-times matching on single string, i makes matching case-insensitive.

This is not a foolproof solution but I think it follows the basic idea and is easy to extend for more universal usage.

Answer (score 0):

We should do this with a HTML/XML processor...

Using just pure perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -i

while(<>){
 s/(<font\s)(.*?)(>)/$1 . repsize($2) . $3 /ge;
 print
}

sub repsize{my $atribs=shift;
  return $atribs =~  s/(size=.)(\d+)/ $1 . $2*2/er;
}
```